# Maven model<modelVersion> version control?

Tags: java, maven

I know that model  for all the 2.x maven 4.0.0. 
Here is what i want to ask

1. How this will be changed in future.
2. What is the purpose of this tag.

Comment: Currently there are plans do change to a new version which will not influence the usage of model version 4.0.0 (http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Model-Version-5-0-0-td5776246.html). But you should keep the information in your pom files to ensure stability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/:

> `modelVersion` This element indicates what version of the object model this POM is using. The version of the model itself **changes very infrequently** but it **is mandatory in order to ensure stability** of use if and when the Maven developers deem it necessary to change the model.

The "model" refers to the structure of `pom.xml` itself, i.e. which elements are allowed/mandatory, how to interpret them, etc.